# Converting from a double loop to a single loop

Tags: python

This program builds a dictionary out of a list based on what two index numbers you would like from the list.
this is the output

{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 'h'}

```
def buildDict2(theList,inputOne,inputTwo) :
    newdict={}
    for a in theList:
        if inputTwo >= len(a):
                print "error"
                return "error"
        if inputOne >= len(a):
                print "error"
                return "error"
        for oneValue in a: 
                    print len(a)

                    varkey=a[inputOne]
                    varvalue=a[inputTwo]
                    newdict[varkey]=varvalue


    return newdict
print buildDict2([["a", "s","d", 2,0,1],["b", "f",3,"h",0,2],["c", "g",5,7]],0,3)
```

How do i convert this to a single loop? 
+1 all answers
thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

basically i just need to use one loop instead of two

edit: important concept: it takes a dictionary and two numbers. the two numbers tell the program what index of the lists to use. list=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[h,g,i]] used with the numbers 0 and 2 will return a dictionary with three entries. the keys will be the first input. so the keys are a d and h, and the values are going to be the list index of second input, so c, e i. get it?

for this code

```
def buildDict2(theList, range1, range2, newdict = {}):
    for a in theList:
        if range2 >= len(a) or range1 >= len(a):
            return "error"
        newdict[a[range1]] = a[range2]
        return newdict
print buildDict2([["a", "s","d", 2,0,1],["b", "f",3,"h",0,2],["c", "g",5,7]],0,3)
```

i am getting {'a': 2}
when i want to get 
{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 'h'}
whats the problem?

Comment: Quick questions, what are `range1` and `range1` (and their values), and why no `list comprehension`?  Are you "cleaning up" a list and converting it into a dictionary? You may want to update your post with some of the answers - thanks.

Comment: hello levon, nice to see you again, being helpful also. range1 and range2 are just poorly named variables. they represent the index number of the element of the list. This program builds a dictionary out of a list based on what two index numbers you would like from the list.

Comment: I... wait what... don't even get whats going on in this code

Comment: so `range1` and `range2` delineate the `start` and `end-1` index of the items in the list you are interested in? Just clarifying.

Comment: @JakobBowyer it takes a dictionary and two numbers. the two numbers tell the program what index of the lists to use. list=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[h,g,i]] used with the numbers 0 and 2 will return a dictionary with three entries. the keys will be the first input. so the keys are a d and h, and the values are going to be the list index of second input, so c, e i. get it?

Comment: no levon, they are just poorly named variables. just rename them inputOne and inputTwo

Comment: @WebMaster see my answer, it passes your example

Comment: yes i have, but please help me understand it better, can you explain what you did? im a student :3

Comment: @WebMaster I don't think that `inputOne` and `inputTwo` are any better. Your variable names should describe what the variable is *for*!

Comment: you put the return statement at the wrong level of indentation. I guess pep8 has some validity after all.

Comment: alright, thank you very much, i got it

Comment: @WebMaster, put `min_len = max([range1, range2])` before `for`, and check `len(a) <= min_len` in `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def buildDict2(theList, range1, range2):
    newdict = {}
    for a in theList:
        if range2 >= len(a) or range1 >= len(a):
            return "error"
        newdict[a[range1]] = a[range2]
    return newdict
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print buildDict2([["a", "s","d", 2,0,1],["b", "f",3,"h",0,2],["c", "g",5,7]],0,3)
```

changed to pep8 indentation as per Jakob's recommendation so you can see the indentation more clearly. you put your return statement at the wrong level.

corrected mutable default as per astynax's comment.

Comment: Standard indentation is 4 spaces. Please fix :(

Comment: wow, thanks for the -1 because you don't like my indentation. I gave you +1 for beating me to the answer.

Comment: what is if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: dont complain about minus one lol, my previous account got had +1-+3 on every post, and one post got 15 negative. banned me from asking questions.

Comment: dont worry ill +1 when i get 15 rep lol
can it be done without "if __name__ == '__main__':"?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx so am I but please stick to pep8

Comment: Web Master: if __name__ == '__main__': is an often-used idiom for doing something when the program is run as opposed to being imported.

Comment: okay awesome.. so how do you make the program work without it?

Comment: the same way you had your original program, just get rid of that line and remove the bottom line's (non-pep8) indentation.

Comment: im getting the output of "{'a': 2}" when i should be getting "{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 'h'}"

Comment: I get: jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ python build.py 
{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 'h'}

Comment: his answer isn't PEP8 + it is actually slower taking 1.14 usec per loop. Where as mine is nearly 944 nseconds

Comment: come on , Jakey, you should know speed is not the most important thing in python. Although, I agree the code looks kinda ugly.

Comment: Its slow, it makes more CPU calls, its inefficient

Comment: Ok folks this thread is being flagged quite a lot, please can you take this to chat?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, don't use mutable object as default value of function argument (`newdict={}`)!!!

Comment: thanks! just googled that; something I hadn't understood. will correct answer now.

Comment: thank you Jakob. Web Master, please consider awarding the "correct answer" to Jakob, who was first.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do this, using `map()` instead of an explicit loop:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> def build_dict(lists, key_idx, value_idx):
...     return dict(map(itemgetter(key_idx, value_idx), lists))
...
>>> build_dict([["a", "s","d", 2,0,1],["b", "f",3,"h",0,2],["c", "g",5,7]],0,3)
{'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 'h'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def buildDict2(theList, pos1, pos2):
    di = {}
    for element in theList:
        try:
            di[element[pos1]] = element[pos2]
        except IndexError:
            return "Error" # <- Idk?
    return di

assert buildDict2([["a", "s","d", 2,0,1],["b", "f",3,"h",0,2],["c", "g",5,7]],0,3) == {'a': 2, 'c': 7, 'b': 'h'}
```

Just a guess.

Comment: okay nice guess, can't really understand it though, what is assert?

Comment: It throws an exception if the statement fails and the statement was comparing my function with your test output.

Comment: assert is simply a "simple" test for seeing if things are what you expect consider this example

Comment: `a = 3; b = 3 + a; assert b == 6`

Comment: i did google it, its weird tho. can't think of a practical use for it

Comment: Its a simple sanity check when you know something should be a value]